# How to get spesific index number from listof Kotlin

Tags: function, kotlin, oop, readline

```
data class foodInfo(
    val name: String,
    val price: Int
)

class Foods {
    private val food = mutableListOf(
        foodInfo("Pizza", 50000),
        foodInfo("Burger", 40000),
        foodInfo("Fried Rice", 40000),
        foodInfo("Noodle", 15000),
        foodInfo("Salad", 5000)
    )

    fun displayMenu() {
        food.forEachIndexed { index, foodInfo ->
            println("${index + 1}. ${foodInfo.name} =  ${foodInfo.price}/porsi")
        }
    }

    fun foodSelected(index: Int){
       val getIndex = food[index]
       println("You pick a number $getIndex")
    }
}

fun main(){
    Foods().displayMenu()
    print("Pick Menu: ")
    
    val selectMenu = readln().toInt()
    Foods().foodSelected(selectMenu)

}
```

How to get spesific index number, name and price from food listof ?

I already tried but i got full object like this foodInfo(name=Pizza, price=50000)

Comment: The line _food[index]_ is wrong, it should be _food[index - 1]_.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
data class foodInfo(
    val name: String,
    val price: Int
)

class Foods {
    private val food = mutableListOf(
        foodInfo("Pizza", 50000),
        foodInfo("Burger", 40000),
        foodInfo("Fried Rice", 40000),
        foodInfo("Noodle", 15000),
        foodInfo("Salad", 5000)
    )
    fun foodSelected(index: Int){
       val getIndex = food[index]
       println("You pick a number $index $getIndex") // Add the index parameter here
    }
}

fun main(){
    Foods().displayMenu()
    print("Pick Menu: ")
    
    val selectMenu = readln().toInt()
    Foods().foodSelected(selectMenu)

}
```

As far as I could understand your question, this could be a possibility of printing the index of the item

Since Lists use 0-based indexing, `index+1` could help you print the exact index. I've just put a hint in the right direction for you

Comment: This answer is wrong. For example if you select _3. Fried Rice_ and type in _3_ you'll get _Noodle_...

Comment: Oh thanks for the heads up, but OP found it correct as per his needs, I will just edit the answer to incorporate your comment

Comment: This change is wrong too. The line _val getIndex = food[index]_ needs to read _val getIndex = food[index - 1]_ to get the correct entry.

Comment: @lukas.j That is not even the point of the question, he just wanted to print the index with the food item printed

Comment: Erroneous code is erroneous code. The way the code is now (both in the question and your answer) will result in printing a wrong answer. For example one picks menu 1. for Pizza, and gets 2. Burger.